# I can't use metro apps and some other cmd apps with proxy on windows 8

Tags: proxy, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

i'm having a problem with my pc (windows 8), the problem is that i use a proxy (located on 127.0.0.1:8080) and i can access websites using my web browser(s), i can also use command line tools that require intenet connectivity like curl (for both http and https), git push, composer, heroku toolbelt and vagrant, but when i try to use tools like ping and other cmd network troubleshooting tools i get a 'request timed out' error. likewise my sublime SFTP plugin gives a 'connection timeout error' and i also cannot use some other apps like windows store app and other windows 8 metro apps.

Please what could be the cause of the error.

Note that i have done/tried the following, yet no avail:
1. set the proxy setting under internet options in command prompt(as expected)
2. set http_proxy and http_proxy environment vars
3. done netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie